# knitr::kable does not pretty print after running an R chunk

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I noticed this weird behavior of `kable` - the pretty printing goes away after running a chunk.

```
> knitr::kable(head(iris, 3))


| Sepal.Length| Sepal.Width| Petal.Length| Petal.Width|Species |
|------------:|-----------:|------------:|-----------:|:-------|
|          5.1|         3.5|          1.4|         0.2|setosa  |
|          4.9|         3.0|          1.4|         0.2|setosa  |
|          4.7|         3.2|          1.3|         0.2|setosa  |
```

Now do File > New File > R Notebook. This creates a demo notebook, with a single chunk containing `plot(cars)`. Execute that chunk within the notebook

```
> plot(cars)
```

Then print the table again. This time the output looks different. Why?

```
> knitr::kable(head(iris, 3))
[1] "| Sepal.Length| Sepal.Width| Petal.Length| Petal.Width|Species |"
[2] "|------------:|-----------:|------------:|-----------:|:-------|"
[3] "|          5.1|         3.5|          1.4|         0.2|setosa  |"
[4] "|          4.9|         3.0|          1.4|         0.2|setosa  |"
[5] "|          4.7|         3.2|          1.3|         0.2|setosa  |"
attr(,"format")
[1] "markdown"
attr(,"class")
[1] "knit_asis"
attr(,"knit_cacheable")
[1] NA



> packageVersion("knitr")
[1] ‘1.17’


> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.3 highr_0.6   knitr_1.17 


> RStudio.Version()
$citation

To cite RStudio in publications use:

  RStudio Team (2016). RStudio: Integrated Development for R. RStudio,
  Inc., Boston, MA URL http://www.rstudio.com/.

A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is

  @Manual{,
    title = {RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R},
    author = {{RStudio Team}},
    organization = {RStudio, Inc.},
    address = {Boston, MA},
    year = {2016},
    url = {http://www.rstudio.com/},
  }


$mode
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘1.0.153’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run that chunk, the `tools:rstudio` environment on the search list is changed to add a function called `print.knitr_kable` which is different from the internal one in the `knitr` package.

Here's what I see before:

```
> ls("tools:rstudio")
[1] "debugSource"              "knit_with_parameters"    
[3] "registerShinyDebugHook"   "RStudio.Version"         
[5] "rstudioDiagnosticsReport" "RStudioGD"               
[7] "source.with.encoding"
```

and here's what I see after:

```
> ls("tools:rstudio")
[1] "debugSource"                 "dplyr_tibble_print_original"
[3] "knit_with_parameters"        "print.knitr_kable"          
[5] "registerShinyDebugHook"      "RStudio.Version"            
[7] "rstudioDiagnosticsReport"    "RStudioGD"                  
[9] "source.with.encoding"
```

For whatever reason, the `tools:rstudio` function is executed instead of the original one.  I can get the original behaviour back by running `detach("tools:rstudio")`, but that messes up Rstudio in several ways, so I don't recommend it.  A less extreme way is to say

```
e <- as.environment("tools:rstudio")
e$print.knitr_kable <- knitr:::print.knitr_kable
```

but that doesn't last:  RStudio apparently fixes it whenever you run a chunk in the notebook.  You could also do an explicit call every time you want to print, e.g.

```
knitr:::print.knitr_kable(knitr::kable(head(iris, 3)))
```

Probably the best solution is for `knitr` to change so it does what RStudio wants when run in an RStudio notebook and the pretty printing otherwise, or for RStudio to change to run the `knitr` function when it's not in a notebook, but I imagine this isn't a huge priority:  if you're running a notebook, why would you care what you see in the console?

Comment: Thanks! knitr:::print.knitr_kable is a reasonable solution. Regarding why I'd care: kable is incredibly useful to pretty print data frames. A typical use case: sharing results with colleagues over Slack. Also, its a little frustrating that running a chunk can change state in this way.

Comment: I've looked a bit more, and this looks like a bug in the RStudio code.  I'll submit a pull request to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for looking that up! I'll go ahead and accept this answer.